# How can I add a caption beneath an image in a basic CSS lightbox?

Tags: html, css, lightbox, caption

I'm using the following code to display a simple lightbox using only CSS. (I'd prefer not to use Javascript).

```css
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  width: 70%;
}

.lightbox figcaption {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed!important;
  top: 70% !important;
  right: 5%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .lightbox img {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .lightbox img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#img1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/sensei/kieflesson.jpg"></a>
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <figure><img src="img/sensei/kieflesson.jpg">
    <figcaption>Test22</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

As you can see I've been trying to put in a caption immediately beneath the image using figcaption. I managed to get it to display, but it isn't responsive. I want it to move with the changing image size.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` for image and caption. `position: fixed` is fine with the wrapper. Right now you have put position: fixed to all wrapper and image also.

Comment: Can i see the code that you have tried with position: absolute.?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It seems my code was a little over-complicated. I achieved the desired effect using the following:

```
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}

.lightbox figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:90%;
    max-width: 500px;}

.lightbox img {
    width:100%;}

.lightbox figcaption {
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```